# Java: HtmlUnit crashes upon JavaScript error

Tags: java, htmlunit

Occasionally HtmlUnit stumbles upon a JavaScript error so grave it brings down the entire application.

Here's the long stacktrace it spits out: http://pastie.org/806625

I have already set the webClient not to throw exceptions on script errors, but this doesn't seem to be helping:

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Can anything be done to help Java recover from this exception, so it can continue executing the rest of the application?

Answer (score 3):

Add below code after initializing the WebClient.

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

And what's the JavaScript code?

If browser works fine with it, then file a bugreport:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=47038&atid=448266